# How to debug Jquery Code in SalesForce?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, salesforce

I am using Jquery Compressed file in salesforce, integration for Google Map. I need to debug my Jquery code but when i put break point to debug my code in firebug then it goes to main.js. I want to debug my code line by line, so i can see variable value. Can we debug code by firebug in salesforce? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you want to debug your own code that uses jquery or do you want to debug jquery?

Comment: yes, i want to debug my own code that is using jquery. But when i put break point then it goes to debug main.js file. I need line by line debug for my Jquery code. @MarcelMeijer

Comment: Don't use break points. I have written and debugged hundreds of thousands of lines of javascript over the years ands never placed a single break point. There are better ways.

Comment: Thanks Beetroot to see my problem and giving suggestion. If i dont use break point then what should i do to check java script code. @ Beetroot-Beetroot

Answer (score 0):

I would add a couple of console.log statements in your javascript code. So you can see where it gets tio in your javascript code and what the value of certain parameters is.

Comment: Thanks for seeing my problem. I need line by line debug for Jquery in salesforce. @Marcel

Answer (score 0):

As JS code runs into a browser js-engine I do not see any difference between debugging js code in salesforce and any other web sites.

Options for debugging:

- breakpoints. I believe that we do not have any difference in salesforce and I have never seen such differences. If you can describe your trouble more detail it might be a start point for further discussion.
- console.log, console.group, etc.
- alerts - please don't do it :)

don't forget to use PrettyPrint for minimized libs.

Comment: Thanks Pavel to seeing my code. How to use console.log in my Jquery Code? Through firebug in Mozilla FireFox, we do debug line by line after activated by press F12. I need to do line by line debug at my Jquery code. But when i put break point and start debug then it direcly goes to main.js file.I need to know how to debug jquery code line by line in firebug for apex page. @Pavel